# Finding 2 different pairs in a roll of 5 different dice

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates, frequency, dice

I have an array of 5 dice and I am trying to check it to see if there are two different pairs. Lets say I have (1,1,2,2,3) or (3,3,4,4,5) i want it to return true. How could i accomplish this?

Comment: Please try something first and then post a question with tried parts.

Answer (score 0):

Let first dice be, int[] firstDice = new int[] { 1,1,2,2,3 };

Let second dice be, int[] secondDice = new int[] { 3,3,4,4,5 };

To check if each pair is different simply iterate over both of them at the same time (provided the number of dice is the same). Here is an example of a method:

```
 private boolean checkDifferentDice(int [] firstDice, int [] secondDice){
 boolean result = true;
 for (int i = 0; i < firstDice.length; i++)
 {
     if (firstDice[i] == secondDice[i])
      return false;
  }
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: Good job serving the code for the OP. That's exactly why SO was made!

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Consider you have an array, arr[5] = {1,1,2,2,3};
You can use Set to solve this. I'm tracking the pair by using count variable.

1,1,2,2,3 --> I'm iterating the array one by one. When I get 1 at first time, I put in set. At second time, check in set, if it contains, then it must be a pair.

```
public bool findSet(int[] arr)
{ 
   HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
   int count = 0; 
   for(int n : arr)
   {
      if(set.contains(n))
      count++;
      else
      set.add(n);
   }
   return count == 2;
 }
```